# What does '$ch' and '-F' stand for in $ch = curl_init();

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL in php. Noticed each time a curl case is initiated, people always put：

```
$ch=curl_init();
```

WHat does '$ch' mean?

```
curl -F template_invoke_name='sendcloud_template'
```

What does '-F' mean?

I've googled around with no answers so hoping to get some here. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the answer to your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859374/curl-f-what-does-it-mean-php-instagram. I'm assuming the answer to your first one is "curl handle".

Comment: 1. Curl Handler 2. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: `$ch` is just the variable name, you could rename it whatever else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ch` is just some variable that holds the cURL handle returned by [curl_init()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php),
and -F refers to form content see, [-F, --form <name=content>](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).
**This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data**

Answer (score 11):

When you call `curl_init()` it initializes a new session and returns a cURL handle. `$ch` is a variable to store the handle (I'm guessing in this instance that `$ch` is a shortened version of `curl handle`). Functions such as `curl_setopt` require a curl handle to be passed in as an argument.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php